# Question mark icon that appears in my web app

Tags: jquery, html

I don't know what the problem is. I put all the correct text encode so that the browser can display the web app correctly. I'm using jQuery Mobile in my web app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false" data-icon="home"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false" data-icon="info"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#three" data-ajax="false" data-icon="mail"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#four" data-ajax="false" data-icon="bars"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<!--Content for 4th Tab-->
  <div id="four">
   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li><a href="profile.html">
        <img src="img/profile.png">
    <h2>Sophia Nicole Sy</h2>
    <p>View your profile</p></a>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<!--END-->

<!--Content for 1st Tab-->
<div id="one">
<form>
     <input type="text" data-mini="true" name="text-4" id="text-4" value="">
<button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Post</button>
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--END-->

<!--Content for 2nd Tab-->
<div id="two">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--END-->


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also put all the required codes so that it can show the web app correctly. Please, need your help.

Comment: Where does your question mark appear ? do you load data ?

Comment: Try specifying a charset.

Comment: It look like this. 
http://s1380.photobucket.com/user/lesliesamonte95/media/ask_zpshizavogm.jpg.html

Comment: Don't know how related to the actual problem but your code has an error: the `ul` inside the `div#one` starts with a closing tag `</li>`.